# error with auth implementation with unity3d and firebase

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, cocoapods

I'm having a little problem. When I try to deploy an unity3d app with the auth sample project from firebase I'm getting this error `"error building Player: iOS framework addition failed due to a CocoaPods installation failure"` but I have installed cocoapods correctly, I even uninstalled it and reinstalled it. I only get this error with the auth project, not with the database. I tried adding the cocoapods to the project with the terminal using pod init instead of having unity do it but nothing seems to work

Comment: Could be https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/1845#issuecomment-425184012

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH YOU A GOD

Comment: Moved to an answer ...

Answer (score 0):

From https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/1845#issuecomment-425184012:

We're working on patching the Firebase C++ and Unity releases to migrate them to the 5.9.0 iOS SDK. In the meantime, under Assets/Firebase/Editor/ there are a set of files matching *Dependencies.xml files (e.g AnalyticsDependencies.xml) that reference the iOS SDK version. You'll need to modify the  section of each file to reference iOS SDK 5.9.0 rather than 5.6.0.

More details at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/1845#issuecomment-425184012

Comment: Once again, Thank you Mr. Beausterien!